# Rails doesn't pick up SECRET_KEY_BASE environment variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, environment-variables, ubuntu-14.04, production-environment

Here's what I'm working with right now:

Ubuntu Trusty 14.04

Rails 4.2.6

Ruby 2.2.3

Passenger

Nginx

When I try to visit the IP I get this message:

```
 Incomplete response received from application
```

When I look at nginx/error.log I see:

```
 Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml`
```

On the server I did:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake secret
```

I placed that result into each of these files for good measure:

```
~/.bashrc
~/.bash_profile
~/.profile
/app/shared/config/local_env.yml
```

For all shell scripts the format is:

```
export SECRET_KEY_BASE="[key]"
```

For the `local_env.yml` I used just:

```
SECRET_KEY_BASE="[key]"
```

I've also tried entering it without quotation marks.

I've restarted the server each time I made a change. No cigar.

What else might be the issue?

-- UPDATE

I've even added the secret key to the secrets.yml file directly. So now I'm thinking my issue is either something to do with passenger/nginx or with a typo somewhere.

Comment: try also export `RAILS_ENV=production` on your server

Comment: what exactly do you mean? Like, set the environemtn to production on the server?

Comment: yes, exactly. or just start the app with RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails s

Comment: I am deploying with capistrano, so when I do `cap production deploy` it should be running server in production. It says `export RAILS_ENV="production"` in the deploy output. How else can I confirm this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is more likely that the environment variables are not actually set rather than Rails is not picking them up. You're raking secrets, which I don't do. I set them up manually in the Unix `etc/environment`, and do not check any secrets into source control. But the following are a few steps that should help you either resolve or hone in on the problem.

**On your Ubuntu server** for system wide environment variables

1- `$env`

Look for your SECRET_TOKEN and SECRET_KEY_BASE. The error tells you that these are not set, this is just a technique to check env. (RAILS_ENV will also be shown in the list if it is set.)

2- `$sudo nano /etc/environment`

Add the following lines -- use your actual values between double quotes. Do not use a [key] or any programmatic replacement.

```
export SECRET_TOKEN="T99ABC..."

export SECRET_KEY_BASE="99ABC..."
```

3- `$logout` / `$login` to reload environment vars

4- `$env` - Check the environment again

Look for your SECRET_TOKEN and SECRET_KEY_BASE to be set.

5- Try deploying again. If it fails, check the environment vars using  `$env` again. It will tell you if something in your deploy is smashing your SECRET_* env vars.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've checked the env variable on the server and the secret base key is in there, but not the secret token. Doesn't rails 4.2+ drop secret_token? Anyway - I added the token direcly to a linked secret.yml file (not checked into git) and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I wholly recommend you ditch the secret.yml file and use Unix directly following the steps above to set the required environment variables; there's no advantage to using the yml that I'm aware of; The Unix etc/environment solution is the best solution (in my opinion). That your secret.yml is not checked into source control makes me wonder how you're deploying it to the server. But it's a complication that isn't needed in the first place.

Comment: It is checked in, the key is not. I'll use this method you're describing. Still not sure why this hacky/direct method isn't working.

Comment: the linked file is what was screwing it up. I removed the linked secrets.yml file and just have the file referencing the env variable and it works. I guess rails can't pick up linked files, or it's not visible at the right time..something like that. Thanks!